# Android widget listview items onclick startActivity call an external app

Tags: java, android, listview, android-widget, onclicklistener

I have to make sure that by clicking on an item in the widget list, an intent is made to an external app.

Intent:

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/"+str));
appIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/"+str));
 try {
     startActivity(appIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    startActivity(webIntent);
}
```

I tried to put this in getViewAt, but it does not work.

```
Intent intent;
try {
  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://status?status_id=" + listItem.id));
  intent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/" + listItem.username + "/status/" + listItem.id));
}
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widgetItemContainer, intent);
```

Comment: Did you call [`setPendingIntentTemplate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setPendingIntentTemplate(int,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) for the `ListView` on the main `RemoteViews`? Also that `try-catch` in the second snippet is pointless. You should instead check if the `intent.resolveActivity()` return is null, and only use the `Intent` if that's not.

Comment: @MikeM.: What do you mean? You could give an example, I'm not sure I understood well.

Comment: For the first part, to see how to use `setPendingIntentTemplate()`, have a look at [the sample `StackView` Widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#implementing_collections) on the developer site. For the second, `ActivityNotFoundException` will not be thrown by that code, so the `try-catch` isn't really doing anything. Instead, after `intent.setPackage()`, check `if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)` before using that `Intent`.